# Show that $\sigma(n)$ = 5 has no solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we define $\sigma(n)$ as the sum of all positive divisors of $n$, is the fact that $\sigma(n)$ = 5 has no solution related to the fact that there is no number $y$ such that $2^y$ = 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sigma(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 12$ is not a power of $2$, so I don't see any immediate connection between the fact that $2^y = 5$ has no solutions and $\sigma(n) = 5$ has no solutions.

---

To address whether $\sigma(n) = 5$ has a solution, notice that $1$ and $n$ are always divisors of $n$, so

$$5 = \sigma(n) \ge n + 1 \implies n \le 4$$

Now there are $4$ options to test.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the sigma function, $\sigma(4)$ = 1+2+4 = 7, $\sigma(3)$ = 1+3 = 4, $\sigma(2)$ = 1+2 = 3 and $\sigma(1)$ = 1, correct? Sorry for the silly question but I just want to make sure that it includes itself... but I suppose it must since we are including 1

Comment: @ArthurCollé Yes, those are correct.